# A small college has 1095 students. What is the approximate probability that more than five students were born on Christmas day?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A small college has 1095 students. What is the approximate probability that more than five students were born on Christmas day? Assume that the birthrates are constant throughout the year and that each year has 365 days.

I tried doing
$X \sim Pn(3) $ and calculating $P(X\gt5)$. My calculation turned out to be 0.22....., which was wrong. (What was wrong with my approximation?). The solution given used a Normal approximation to get an answer of 0.0735. When I tried using a Normal approximation, I was still unable to get that answer. Here is how I attempted it.

$ N\sim(3,1092/365)$.
$ P(X\gt5)=P(N\gt4.5) $  #continuity correction
$= P\left(Z\gt\frac{4.5-3}{\sqrt{\frac{1092}{365}}}\right)$
=$ P(Z>0.86721)$.
=$0.193$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If "more than five" means "six or more" then your continuity correction should be $5.5$.  You also have a minor question of $1095$ or $1092$

Comment: the second parameter is the variance, which should be $(1095)( \frac{1}{365} )( \frac{364}{365}) $

Comment: I'll try the continuity correction with 5.5. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{1092}{365}$ is a mean number of people with the birthday on that day. Why is this a variance?

Comment: $ \frac{1092}{365} $ is the value of n*p*(1-p)

Answer (score 3):

poisson probability distribution $\lambda = 1095 / 365$ 
then calculate

using

$P(N) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \exp(-\lambda)$

1 - P(0) - P(1) - P(2) - P(3) - P(4) - P(5) =

$1 - \exp(-\lambda)(1 + \lambda + \lambda^2 / 2! + \lambda^3 / 3! + \lambda^4/4! + \lambda^5/5!) = .084$

note this is an approximation,

also assuming that 5 is NOT included

Comment: (+1) If we carry this out to a few more places, we get $0.083917942$, which is quite close to the exact probability of $0.08364126$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of having exactly $k$ people with birthdays on Christmas would be
$$
\binom{1095}{k}\frac1{365^k}\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{1095-k}
$$
Adding these probabilities for at most $5$ people, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^5\binom{1095}{k}\frac1{365^k}\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{1095-k}=0.916358737
$$
Thus, the probability that more than $5$ people have their birthday on Christmas, is $0.083641263$.

Answer (score -2):

N should be 5.5 not 4.5

P(X>5) = P(N >5.5) // continuity correction

N~(μ,σ^2)

N~(3,2.99) <--- σ^2 should not be (1092/365)

μ = n*p(amount of students)*(probability of person born on Christmas Day)

=1095 *(1/365)

=3

σ = sqrt(n*p(1-p))

= sqrt(1095*(1/365)(1-(1/365)))

= sqrt(3*(364/365))

= sqrt(2.99)

P(X > 5) = P(X > 5.5)

```
      = P(Z >(5.5-3)/(sqrt(2.99)))         //Z =((X-μ)/σ)

      = P(Z > 1.45)      //using the Standard Normal Probabilities table

      = 0.0735
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkLk.jpg)

Comment: We like posts to be self contained.  Links can fail and often do.  If you can't be bothered to write it up, don't post it.  I looked at the image and it wasn't clear from a glance how to follow the reasoning.

Comment: This is quite difficult to read.  Proper formatting using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would be *really* helpful.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thanks for the comment appreciated

Comment: @RossMillikan got it thanks for telling